# my camera won't track my ball

Tags: camera

i have a scene (scenefile link below) in which a ball (soft body) rolls down the stairs.

the camera is moving on a circle around the scene (which works) and i hoped that i could track the ball with the track to modifier, but the camera does not show the ball when it is moving.

Can somebody help me?

blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1u6g2w854imemn9/camera_track_to.png?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a softbody simulation the mesh moves away from the origin (while the origin stays in the same place). And the Track To constraint tracks the origin.

But you can alternatively also track a vertex group.

Select the ball object, go into Edit Mode > Vertex Select. Select a central vertex (or simply all of them). Go to Properties > Object Data Properties > Vertex Groups and click Add Vertex Group (the little plus icon) and click Assign. Finaly for Vertex Group: in the Track To constraint select the newly made group. The camera should now track the group, and subsequently the ball.

Comment: Thanks!!! works!